# Webpack and Dojo Toolkit

Tags: javascript, dojo, webpack

I'm trying to build dojo with webpack but getting this error

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/matt/Documents/react-bootstrap/node_modules/dojo/i18n.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at DependenciesBlock.loadPitch (/Users/matt/Documents/react-bootstrap/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:191:17)
at DependenciesBlock.doBuild (/Users/matt/Documents/react-bootstrap/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:239:4)
at DependenciesBlock.build (/Users/matt/Documents/react-bootstrap/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:66:14)
```

It seems to be a problem with the dojo loader modules i18n, text , has etc.

Has anyone tried this or has anyone any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: There is an open issue related to this question: [#890](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/890).

Answer (score 2):

The [dojo-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/OpenNTF/dojo-webpack-plugin) provides the ability to build Dojo 1.x applications with Webpack

Answer (score 1):

There is [this project](https://github.com/Nordth/dojo-webpack-loader) that seems to solve this problems.

By the way: thanks a lot to the project author!

Comment: How do you use this?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Nordth/dojo-webpack-loader-examples) are some examples.